# Bootstrap: How to make repeated divs go around a fixed div

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to accomplish the following, make repeated divs "go around" a fixed div. The content of the repeated divs will be created dynamically using Bootstrap thumbnails.

Here's an image that illustrates what i'm trying to do:
[image: a busy cat]

How can i do this with CSS (or Javascript, or who knows... Bootstrap)?

Comment: Sometimes, rather than trying to get div's to line up, what you might need is just a table...

Comment: @johnSmith can you be more specific? I'm already using col-md in this project.

Comment: @tonyWilk how can i accomplish that using tables? (btw, i'm not very fond of using tables to create layouts)

Comment: Why does it have to be a fixed div? Why cant you float all the elements to the right, with the green div first, this will float the other elements around it.

Comment: hi @jmg, that could be a possible solution but it doesn't work like i want it to. With your approach the last elements get aligned to the right and leave an empty space in the left. I would like that the other way around, in other words, looking at the image above, i would like the 9th element to be placed below the 5th element and not below the 8th.

Comment: Another option would be to absolute position all the elements exactly where you want them.

Comment: i was looking for something more simple and mobile friendly :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to it with simple CSS :

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
    background: #2ecc71;
   width: 460px;
   height: 460px;
   margin: 10px;
    float: right;
}
.item {
    background: #e74c3c;
    width: 220px;
   height: 220px;
   margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
   <div class="block"></div>
  
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know tables are a bit out of fashion, however...

```
<table border="1" style="width:300px;">
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>    
  <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">hello</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>        
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>        
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

apologies for the `border="1"`, it's just handy to demo what's going on.

Comment: thanks for the fast exemplification. Using this approach i have to manually add the repeated content in order for it to work, and i can't do that in my case :-/